# How to remove sequence of characters from NSString

Tags: ios, regex

I have a string which contains characters and I need to find out a shortest string or remove sequence of characters from that string.

```
Eg: NSString *string = @"FIRSTEXAMPLEEXAMPLETEST";
Output: FIRSTEXAMPLETEST
```

Can you please help me on finding a suitable `Regex format` to achieve it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `(.+)\1+` regex that will match the longest consecutive substrings and replace with their single occurrences using the 1st backreference `$1`.

Use

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *string = @"FIRSTEXAMPLEEXAMPLETEST";
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(.+)\\1+" options:nil error:&error];
NSString *modifiedString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length]) withTemplate:@"$1"];
NSLog(@"%@", modifiedString); // => FIRSTEXAMPLETEST
```

See [Objective-C demo](https://ideone.com/Sec3U2)

**Pattern details**:

- `(.+)` - Group 1 capturing one or more characters other than newline (use `(?s)` flag before to allow matching newlines with the dot)
- `\1+` - one or more occurrences of the same substrings captured in Group 1.

Comment: Thank you very much. I missed to use $1 which keeps 1st backreference.